# Call a Angular Route from outside the app

Tags: angular, routes

I've created an Angular 9 App which runs inside an ASP.NET MVC Site. So only a small part of my page is written in Angular. I have a main navigation outside my angular app, but the app has its "own" internal routes, which are working fine until I call them inside my Angular App.

My Problem is, when I've opened the page with my angular App then I want to change the URL to a route the angular app knows and the app should load this content from the called route outside the app, WITHOUT reloading the complete app/site.

I've changed the URL outside my app with

```
window.history.pushState(undefined, "Page 1", "/Home/Privacy/page1/test");
```

and the URL changes to a known URL of my angular app, but the angular app is not loading this page, because it's not getting any change detection for route changes I think.

So is it possible to call an Angular route outside from angular app?

Comment: I have no direct answer to your question, just a word of advice based on my experience with angular page embedded into MVC - drop it, and go with one or the other, even it seems like a lot of work. It took us way too long to realize that it takes much more time fixing the odd issues and looking for workarounds than actually re-writing half of the app.

Comment: @TotallyNewb I know, but I don't want to use Server side Rendering for the part of the app google needs to index and the static pages are good with mvc but the member area needs to be more flexible with an App and I did not want to write the hole navigation also in my angular app so I tried to use master page and embed the angular app on some places where I need them.

Comment: I had a similar requirement to enable testing with Playwright. First I tried to use `setLocation` function from protector https://playwright.dev/docs/protractor/#polyfilling-waitforangular without success. Next I tried getAngularTestability to use findProviders to obtain router but discovered findProviders is not yet implemented and always return empty array. Next I tried to use `ng` global variable (does require app to be in dev mode) https://angular.io/api/core/global so I could use injector or app component to access router to call navigateByUrl but it seems to return false for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried just rendering hidden links on page within ng app and submitting click event on them outside the app?